# Delete entire line in text file based on item in table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a table generated by my get action. It pulls the data from a text file and splits it by the pipeline, so it does the below...

```
This|03-26-2019 01:14:53 PM
is a test|03-26-2019 01:15:08 PM
of the|03-26-2019 01:15:16 PM 
EMERGENCY BROADCAST SYSTEM|03-26-2019 01:15:29 PM 
!!!
```

becomes

[image: Example table]

Below is my table

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Paygroups</th>
        <th>Date added</th>
        <th>Modify</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var record in Model.Files)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@record.Paygroups </td>
            <td>@record.DateAdded </td>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "UpdateFiles") | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "UpdateFiles") </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

and below is my method for deleting

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(string Paygroup)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var fullpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/sourcefiles"), "paygroup.txt");
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fullpath, System.IO.File.ReadLines(fullpath).Where(l => l != Paygroup).ToList());
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "UpdateFiles");
    }
```

Obviously, the code in there won't work as is, since it's looking for a paygroup entered in the editor field to be sent as "Paygroup". The problem with that is since my text file is setup as paygroup|datetime it won't be able to find the line if only the paygroup is entered.

I thought about reading the entire file into an array, storing each line, do a contain "paygroup" search in the array, then removed the line that contained it and wrote the new array to a text file. I figured that could be better optimized if I was actually able to put the delete button on the row next to the paygroup and date added, that way it could grab the rows data, recombine them with a pipeline, and delete it from the text file? I'm not exactly sure where to start with that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line of text in the file always starts with the "pay group" (and a pipe character), then why not simply:

```
.Where(l => !l.StartsWith($"{Paygroup}|"))
```

or, in earlier syntax:

```
.Where(l => !l.StartsWith(string.Format("{0}|", Paygroup)))
```

Comment: because I actually did not think of using .StartsWith. Thank you!